# Create a function of counting number of elements in a list in r

Tags: r

I am counting the number of elements in each column in a list, I am wondering how to create a function to make the progress faster

```
c1   c2   c3   c4
4    3    3     4
2    4    4     5
1    2    4     3
3    4    3     5
```

The number 1-5 is the scale of the survey, c1 - c4 is the column name. For now I use`lenght(which(list$c1 == "1"))` to count the number of element "1" in c1 column but I have hundreds more lists and columns to go.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `colSums(list == 1, na.rm = TRUE)`  assuming the `list` mentioned is `data.frame`

Comment: Thanks! One more question, my data also contains missing values (NAs), and the ```colSums``` command does not work on NAs. Is there any way to count the number of NAs?

Answer (score 1):

The strategy suggested by akrun in comments may be best

````
my_list <- read.table(text = "c1   c2   c3   c4
4    3    3     4
2    4    4     NA
1    2    NA    3
3    4    3     5", header = T)

my_list
  c1 c2 c3 c4
1  4  3  3  4
2  2  4  4 NA
3  1  2 NA  3
4  3  4  3  5

#count responses with 1
colSums(my_list == 1, na.rm = T)
c1 c2 c3 c4 
 1  0  0  0 

#OR
colSums(my_list == 3, na.rm = T)
c1 c2 c3 c4 
 1  1  2  1

#count no responses
colSums(is.na(my_list))
c1 c2 c3 c4 
 0  0  1  1 
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
> table(stack(df))
      ind
values c1 c2 c3 c4
     1  1  0  0  0
     2  1  1  0  0
     3  1  1  2  1
     4  1  2  2  1
     5  0  0  0  2
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(c1 = c(4L, 2L, 1L, 3L), c2 = c(3L, 4L, 2L, 4L), 
    c3 = c(3L, 4L, 4L, 3L), c4 = c(4L, 5L, 3L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,    
-4L))
```